# SQL - how to return rows containing ALL children rows

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-ce

Given a parent + reference tables where `Reference` table is as follows

```
Ref_ID    PARENT_ID    
-------------------
1           1            
2           1            
1           2       
3           2       
1           3       
3           3       
4           3       
2           4       
3           4
```

I'm trying to return all distinct parent rows where `ref_id` contains both 2 & 3

The query

```
SELECT *
FROM  Parent 
WHERE parent_id in (SELECT parent_id from XRefTable where ref_id in (2, 3) )
```

returns all parent_id 1, 2, 3, 4

WHEREAS the correct result required is to return parent_id 4 which has BOTH ref_id's 2 & 3, others have EITHER 2 OR 3

Any help is appreciated

FYI - there are 4-7 tables in the query (depending on user selections) so performance is a huge factor

SORRY cannot use stored procedures as it has to work on SQL Server CE too

Comment: how many distinct ref_id values are there? Also how many distinct parent_id values? Also do you expect these to grow over time?

Comment: @Tobsey these are user-defined - both by definition and for selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT parent_id 
 from XRefTable 
 where ref_id in ( 2, 3 ) 
 group by PARENT_ID 
 having count(distinct ref_id) = 2
```

Comment: looks good, any thoughts on optimizing it, the complete query is something like SELECT * from ParentTable WHERE parent_id in ( .....<the query above>.... ) which is currently giving a cost of 0.0048914 in the sample data with all relevant columns indexed to the query

Comment: Sorry, currently I don't have an idea to improve the speed furthermore.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do a set-wise comparison.  For this, I strongly recommend the `group by` and `having` clauses:

```
select parent_id
from Reference r
group by parent_id
having sum(case when ref_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when ref_id = 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Each component of the `having` clause is counting one of the fields.  The logic requires that both are present.

The reason that I prefer this approach over others is because you can change the logic, using essentially the same structure.

If you have the list in a comma delimited string, the following will work.  Perhaps not "elegant" and "relational", but it works:

```
set @Ref_ids = "1,2,3,4"

select parent_id
from Reference r
where charindex(','+cast(ref_id as varchar(255))+',', '+@ref_ids+',') > 0
group by parent_id
having count(distinct ref_id) = (len(replace(@ref_ids, ',', '')) - len(@ref_ids))+1
```

This is doing string manipulation to determine whether the ref_id is in the list.  The `having` clause then counts the number of matches, making sure that it is the same size as the list.  This will work, assuming there are no spaces in the list and no blank values.

Comment: interesting idea but quickly becomes unwieldy when the query becomes ref_id in (2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, 15, 18, ....)

Comment: How is your list of ref_ids being stored?

Comment: The table is defined like above, the list of ref_ids is generated based on user input where clicking on an item in a UI list updates the results on the screen from this query, furthermore, the items in the list are also user defined so we really have no idea of how many items could potentially be in the query/ref_ids, hence the comment

Comment: Are  you storing the list in a string (presumably comma delimited) or in a table?

Comment: No, the ref_id in ( .... ) is generated based on user input and not persisted at all

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
SELECT 
    ParentReference.Parent_ID
FROM
    ParentReference
    INNER JOIN ParentReference B ON ParentReference.Parent_ID = B.Parent_ID AND ParentReference.Ref_ID = 2 AND B.Ref_ID = 3
```

Comment: interesting idea but quickly becomes unwieldy when the query becomes ref_id in (2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, 15, 18, ....)